# Should I avoid considering to answer downvoted questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

On a number of occasions I've tried to assist newcomers to Stackoverflow. Some of these questions aren't necessarily as good as they should be. I realise we have guidelines for this, trying to guarantee the quality of questions and answers. I recently have some bad experience with answering these questions: It happened because people had downvoted the question, or at least commented and pointed to the guides on asking questions. It seems that, trying to answer the question then always results in a downvote for the answer, no matter how much effort that answer took.

An example: [What does it mean when an object is static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052261/what-does-it-mean-when-an-object-is-static/48053280#48053280)

Since that experience, I'm now just filtering ALL questions with a single downvote. If those are the rules, then so be it. But it feels a high price to pay for quality. One of the aims of Stackoverflow should also be to help people, even the new guys, no? We've all started from 0, no?

Comment: _"to **help** people, even the new guys, no?"_ [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179009/159251). At least, not exactly.

Comment: The goal of SO is **not** to help single users. It is to build a long lasting repository of good questions. There is no general rule to not answer downvoted questions, but you shouldn't answer close-worthy ones. An answer with a positiv score on a closed question [prevents automatic deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) which might be the reason to downvote such answers.

Comment: The question you link is not awful, and notably it only has a single downvote. It consists of someone trying to understand stuff, which is good. But it could still be improved by the asker having maybe _run the code_ they they're asking about, and probably boiled down to just question number 4. Also, pro tip, if you find yourself writing an answer that says "I try to answer your questions, although, there are some bits that aren't fully clear", and your first move in that answer is to link to a tutorial, you probably should think twice about answering.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's clear.